# Shade area between two Y values

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a list of values with ListPlot and then:

1. add a horizontal line
2. add an error band to the horizonal line, i.e., a shaded area with the horizontal line at its center.

So far I'be been able to plot both things with Epilog, using also Thickness to create the band. The problem is that Epilog is rendered after the main plot, resulting in an overlap between the shaded area and the lines joining the dots, as you can see in the picture (it is just an example for 15 random numbers between 0 and 10 with the band at y=5). I would like the band to be underneath the joined dots, and, if possible, I would like to do it avoiding the use of Show.

Here's the code in case it helps:

```
ListPlot[Data, Epilog -> {{Lighter[Gray, 0.8], Thickness[0.02], 
Line[{{0, 5}, {14.9, 5}}]}, {Black, Dashed, 
Line[{{0, 5}, {14.9, 5}}]}}]
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: "I would like the band to be underneath the joined dots" - have you already tried using `Prolog` instead of `Epilog`?

Comment: Please supply values for your list. "Data".

Comment: I didn't know about Prolog, but that seems to perfectly solve the problem (I did search for a function like Epilog that is rendered before the plot, but somehow it didn't came up). Thank you!

Comment: Look in the `See Also` section of the documentation for `Epilog`.